# Stream video with ffmpeg to icecast?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

Is there a simple way to stream video with ffmpeg into icesast?
Source video is in `video/x-matroska` format. Streams themselves are in various formats (mpeg, vorbis, aac, etc.). I want ffmpeg to guess source on it's own and then trans-code it into anything playable by browsers "on the fly", keeping source resolution and aspect ratio. `video/webm` will do.
I tried doing this (Including playing with output formats):

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -vcodec libvpx -cpu-used -5 -deadline realtime -content_type video/webm\
    icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/vstream.webm
```

But stream is not playable and connections cause ffmpeg to terminate with following error:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
Error writing trailer of icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/vstream.webm: Connection reset by peer
```

Involving anything besides ffmpeg is fine, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is either hard to achieve or is not possible at all. Nevertheless, it is possible to achieve something similar with combination of `nginx` (with `rtmp` module) and `ffmpeg`. In `nginx` config (Probably located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) following section should be appended to make it work as `rtmp` server (*With full public access. Be careful, stream is not encrypted and anyone capable of reaching your network can watch it*):

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            allow play all;
        }
    }
}
```

Then streaming video file is as easy as invoking `ffmpeg` like this:

```bsh
ffmpeg -re -i video_file.mkv -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://host:1935/live
```

Finally, anyone who want to watch the stream should connect to the very same address with their player of choice:

```
rtmp://host:1935/live
```

Note: `host` here is the host name of the server where `nginx` is launched.

Answer (score 0):

short answer, you can't , because icecast is a audio streaming system, not a video streaming server.

Comment: From official website: "Icecast is a streaming media (audio/**video**) server which currently supports Ogg (Vorbis and Theora), Opus, WebM and MP3 streams."

Answer (score 0):

With obs it works just fine, haven't tried with ffmpeg though. And obs has the advantage that you get player controls to seek back and forth. I followed this guide and it's very easy:

https://www.braillealphabetsoup.com/icecast-video-streaming-with-obs.html